# Postgresql database doesn't exist in travis ci after being created

Tags: node.js, postgresql, travis-ci

After adding postgresql to my app, each time my test run on travis i get an error saying that the databese does not exist when i run a database.js in my travis.yml.
But my tests are passing locally
this is my .yml file

```
services:
  - postgresql
before_script:
  - travis_wait 30 yarn install
  - "psql -c 'create database myDiary;' -U postgres"
  - travis_wait npm install
  - node build/models/database.js
```

this is my connection in database.js

```
const connectionString = 'postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5432/myDiary';

const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();
```

and attached is my travis output

Travis CI error ouput

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Travis is not creating the myDiary database because the entire line is stringified. Only the command following -c should be a string.

```
services:
  - postgresql
before_script:
  - travis_wait 30 yarn install
  - psql -c 'create database myDiary;' -U postgres
  - travis_wait npm install
  - node build/models/database.js
```